# Convex 3D polygonal object

Tags: polygon

I need a mathematical approach to check if a 3D polygonal object is convex.
In other words, how can one determine mathematically if a 3D polygonal object is convex by knowing the vertexes of the polygon.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that a polygon is concave by taking each face and then replacing all the vertices in the plane equation of the face:

1. if they have the same sign it means that the face delimits the polygon in a certain direction => the test succeeds; proceed to next face
2. if they have different signs => this face cuts another face => the polygon is concave.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D polygon is convex if the angles of all vertices have same direction (ie all angling to the left or all angling to the right). However, I'm not sure about 3D polygons.